# set hover color dynamically

Tags: css, drupal

I'm using drupal and I created a color field to be used in variable to make contents with differents color, there is an example of a dump :

[image]

and I use it like this on my content in twig :

```
<p style="{{ node_color ? 'color:' ~ node_color }}">{{ content.field_formated_title.0 }}</p>
```

Now I want to use this color on hover buttons, but I don't really know how to do that, should I do something in my css or js?

Comment: You can do this using CSS variables. https://codepen.io/jimratliff/full/dxOwLo

Answer (score 0):

Normaly css is for style, so i would write custom css-file and write hover-css there.

Sorry, i do not know whether there is a command for your way - did not found anything.